# Which file contains Localization info in an iPhone Xcode project?

Tags: iphone, xcode, localization

I am working on a iPhone app and trying to add a German localization. And we are using TFS for version control.

I have added the German strings file all right, but every time I restart Xcode, the Localizable.strings(German) is gone. The file still exists on disk, but just not included in the project.  I believe it's because some controlling file is read-only. I have to find this file and explicitly check it out. I cannot checkout/check-in the whole project because the guy integrate the code will be mad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the xxxxx.xcodeproj folder.